# Showing Image in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a Django web app where I am uploading an image and showing some texts. But I am not able to show the image in the front end after uploading.

`views.py`

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    elif request.method == "POST":
        input_file = request.FILES['file']
        media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(input_file.name, input_file)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        filepath = os.path.join(media_root, filename)
        images = segment_lines(filepath)
        extracted_text = extract()
        copy2(filepath, '/home/user/ocr/ocr/static/'+ filename)
        response = { "response" : extracted_text, "img": filename}
        return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

`index.html`

```
<form action="" id="file-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-9">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-group">
                   <div class="input-group-prepend">
                       <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
                    </div>
                </div>           
            </div>            
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
          <span class="upload-btn">
          <button type="submit" id='upload-button' class="btn btn btn-outline-dark">Extract</button>
          </span>
      </div>
     </div>
 </form>
<div class="row" style="border:none;">
      <div class="col-xs-6 mx-auto" id="img_data">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 mx-auto" id="content_data">
      </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = document.getElementById('file-form');
    var fileSelect = document.getElementById('inputGroupFile01');
    var uploadButton = document.getElementById('upload-button');

    form.onsubmit = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Processing ...';
      var file = fileSelect.files[0];
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file, file.name);
      formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', true);

      xhr.onload = function () {

        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Extract';
          var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          var follow_up = data['response'];
          var corrected = data["correct_response"]
          var demoid = document.getElementById("content_data");

          var btnid = document.getElementById('btn-data')
          var imgid = document.getElementById('img_data')
          var img_path = data["img"]
          var final_content = follow_up;
          demoid.innerHTML = '<h3>Extracted Text</h3><p id="rcorners3">' + final_content + '</p>'
</script>
```

How can I show the uploaded image here, I have little experience with javascript so If anyone can help me on this!

what I tried so far is, I passed the image path URL, and using {% static %} tried to show the image like below

```
imgid.innerHTML = '<h3>Your Image</h3><img class="id-of-img-tag" src="" alt="img" style="width:300px;height:300px;margin-right:15px;">'
document.querySelector(".id-of-img-tag").src = "{% static " + img_path + " %}";
```

Comment: Does the `data["img"]` value contain the correct route to the image in your static folder?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct image file name, which I am using later.

Comment: is your img_path correct?

Comment: I used console.log to see data["img"] there it is showing the correct file name. But when I inspect the element it is showing like this `<img class="id-of-img-tag" src="/static/%20%2B%20img_path%20%2B%20" alt="img" style="width:300px;height:300px;margin-right:15px;">`

Comment: Could you also show us that `extract()` function? I find it suspicious that it doesn't accept the input filename as a parameter.

Comment: `extract()` is actually reading files from line segmented images which were written into a folder. So basically it doesn't take any input, it's just returning the extracted text.

Comment: The segmentation function should then return a list of filenames. Otherwise you'll have problems down the line with concurrent requests trashing that folder's contents.

Comment: Let me clear the working of those functions; first, the image is uploaded and then it segmented into several images which are writing to a temp folder, which later use to extract text from each image and combine them into a single string. That extracted text is coming properly, but the image is not coming. And in the static folder the image is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path to your image is valid, then you should create an image with the `new Image()` constructor. This is similar to doing `document.createElement('img')` to create an image. The constructor returns a `HTMLImageElement` instance, which is basically the JavaScript equivalent to the `<img>` element.

To ensure proper loading listen for the `load` event on the image. So that when the image has been downloaded you can add it to the page.

Then set the `src` property of the image (which will also set the attribute) to start the download of the image from your static folder.

```
...
var btnid = document.getElementById('btn-data')
var imgid = document.getElementById('img_data')
var img_path = data["img"]

var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var title = document.createElement('h3');
  title.textContent = 'Your image';
  image.className = 'id-of-img-tag';
  image.alt = 'img';
  image.style.width = '300px';
  image.style.height = '300px';
  image.style.marginRight = '15px';
  imgid.append(title, image);
}, {once: true});
image.src = img_path;

var final_content = follow_up;
demoid.innerHTML = '<h3>Extracted Text</h3><p id="rcorners3">' + final_content + '</p>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use `fs.url()` to reconstitute the URL to your saved image.

Also, as discussed in the comments, `segment_lines()` should really return a list of filenames that `extract_text()` will use. Otherwise, if/when you're using a single temporary folder, concurrent requests will cause havoc.

```py
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.http import JsonResponse


def extract_text(input_paths):
    # ... Do some magic using the input paths ...
    return 'hello'


def segment_lines(image_path):
    return [
        # ... file paths for segmented result...
    ]


def handle(request):
    input_file = request.FILES['file']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(input_file.name, input_file)
    images = segment_lines(fs.path(filename))
    extracted_text = extract_text(images)
    response = {"response": extracted_text, "img_url": fs.url(filename)}
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

A simplified version of your HTML, then, using `fetch()` and form data:

```
<form action="" id="file-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
    <button type="submit" id='upload-button' class="btn btn btn-outline-dark">Extract</button>
</form>
<div id="content_data"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var form = document.getElementById('file-form');
  var uploadButton = document.getElementById('upload-button');

  form.onsubmit = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Processing ...';
    fetch('/', {body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        const demoid = document.getElementById('content_data');
        demoid.innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
        // or to show the image:
        // demoid.innerHTML = `<img src="${data.img_url}"/>`;
      });
  };
</script>
```

There may definitely be something I've missed here.

Comment: But in your html example how will show the image in the html?

Comment: @AlokKumarPadhi Amended.

Comment: Yeah I agree, for concurrent requests I am going to modify my code.